# Django: What's the best practice on structuring global templatetags?

Tags: django

I realize that templatetags are mainly used specific to applications which are INSTALLED_APPS, such as articles/templatetags/, but in my case I need tags for generic things such as navigation which doesn't have an application.

I'm currently keeping `templatetags` in my project dir. and in order for it to get picked up I added my project to `INSTALLED_APPS` - this works but I'm not sure if this was the right thing to do - are there any downsides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it the same way Django provides its additional template tags, i.e. creating an own package/application( `django.contrib.humanize`, `django.contrib.markup`, `django.contrib.webdesign`)

These are just three "normal" packages, that have a `templatetags` package inside. The name of the module inside `tempaltetags` is the same as the package/application name (e.g. `humanize.py`).

Then put it somewhere where Python can find it.

You could also create some kind of "meta" package `templatetags` and put everything there, e.g.

```
templatetags
 - navigation
   - __init__.py
   - templatetags
      - _init__.py
      - navigation.py
 - other
  - ...
```

Of course you have to add those to you `INSTALLED_APPS` (e.g. `templatetags.navigation`) and load them in your template (e.g. `{% load navigation %}`).